# CDT installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have installed `cdt-master-6.0.2.zip` ([link](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/galileo/dist/cdt-master-6.0.2.zip)) to my Eclipse by extracting it to the Eclipse installation dir. I'm using **Eclipse 3.5** in **Windows 7 x86** machine. But the plugin doesn't show up when I start Eclipse (I can't create a new cpp project). Yet cdt shows up in **Help > About Eclipse SDK > About Eclipse SDK Features**. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install plug-ins into Eclipse you should always prefer using the user interface through *Help > Install new software* menu.

Anyway if you really want to install plug-ins manually into your Eclipse installation, you have to place them into the *dropins* folder.
BUT this way you will have to resolve plug-in dependencies by yourself. If all dependencies are not satifsied, the concerned plug-ins will fail to start silently. This is why you should REALLY prefer to use the standard plug-in installation method to avoid any problem.